# How to change both the text of the command prompt and the color?

Tags: command-line

I want my command prompt to be like this:

```
xyz$
```

but in green.  So I put into my bashrc some code I found yet it does not work.

```
PS1="xyz\[\032[COLOR]m\]$"
```

This changes the command prompt to

```
xyz�[COLOR]m$
```

How can I get this to work?

I found this works but unfortunately now all the text is green - even the text after the prompt! Getting closer. I want the text that follows the prompt to look like it always did.

```
PS1="\[\033[0;32m\]xyz$ "
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Answer (score 0):

You should add `reset` code after changing color.
`\033[00m` resets your prompt color.

In addition, your PS1 makes your prompt `[]xyz$` .
If you want `xyz$`  without `[]`, please set as below:

```
PS1="\033[0;32mxyz\033[00m$ "
```